# Not able to change port from 80 to any other port in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So i have created an EC2 instance in AWS  and i have attached security group for this which has HTTP port 80 which comes by default .
I also has assigned public ip for this instance and which is working fine .

When i change port of my IIS serve to 8080 or 800 or anything page is not able to display .
Even i have changed to Custom TCP rule and given that port but still i am not able to access from outside of AWS .
I have tried accessing using DNS as well .

Can some one help me resolve this ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access any port of EC2 instance you must do below things:

On EC2 instance do not enable firewall, instead of this we have AWS service called **Security Group** which helps us to access respective instance ports as required.

Now, you must have a security group which has **Http port 80** and **ssh port 22** enabled (port 22 for secure shell), so now you can add **port 8080** or any other ports in that list of **inbound rules**. I have attached screenshot below:

[image: Security Group screenshot]

Now, try to access your ports from outside (you can put **http://publicIP of ec2 instance:8080** in browser to check if port is accessable from outside), and check if its working fine. Also make sure to have **openSSH** on machine from where your'e going to access EC2 instance.

Comment: Let me try and i will update you soon thank you for the suggestions